# How to test .aar inside Java?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I would like to test my server using my mobile SDK (.aar).
Therefore, I am importing my .aar to my Java project.

The question is how do I mock my Application Context in my non Android environment ?

Comment: Just for my understanding: you created an Android app which runs a server and you want to test it? Why don't you create an Android instrumentation test instead of an Java project?

Comment: Because i want isolate the mobile overhead.

Comment: In this case, I am wondering, why you created an Android library if you want to avoid the Android overhead. Just to be sure, are you using any Android specific code in your library? If so, you won't be able to isolate the overhead as it will require the Android runtime. If you don't want that, remove all the references to an Android context or something. You may still use the Android Java code, if it does not depend on a Context.

Comment: I don't to run test and be depend on the emulator \ phone.

Comment: This won't work. You cannot access a Context without having the appropriate runtime. See http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html. The only thing I see here, is to create JUnit tests which only test specific classes or modules of your server or service without actually creating the server.